# Exit array for loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, exit

Consider my code below:

```
    System.out.println("Insert your inventory");
    for (int i = 0; i<20;i++) {
       System.out.print(i+1+".");
       if (inventory[i] == "N" || inventory[i]=="n") {
          break;
       }
       inventory[i] = s.nextLine();     
    }
```

How can I exit from this loop if the user enters 'N' or 'n'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare your String variables with the `.equals()` method instead of the `==` operator.

An explanation about why this is important can be found [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing string with `==` operator. It does not yield correct result because your constant string "N" and your input "N" do not have same reference/pointer.

You have to use `equals()` to guarantee the correct compare result between strings.

Replace

```
if (inventory[i] == "N" || inventory[i]=="n")
```

With

```
if (inventory[i].equals("N") || inventory[i].equals("n"))
```